# How to get specific phrases from data frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I filtered a column in my data frame that contains the word "no". I want to print the phrases that have "no" in them.

For instance, if this is my dataset:

```
index | Column 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  0   | no school for the rest of the year. no homework and no classes
  1   | no more worries. no stress and no more anxiety
  2   | no teachers telling us what to do
```

I want to get words/phrases that come after the word "no". As you can see, the word "no" occurs more than 1 time in some strings. I'd want my output to be

```
no school
no homework
no classes
no more worries
no stress
no more anxiety
no teachers
```

This is my code so far :

```
#make a copy of the column I'd like to filter
copy = df4['phrases'].copy()

#find rows that contain the word 'no'
nomore = copy.str.contains(r'\bno\b',na=False)

#split words in each string
copy.loc[nomore] = copy[nomore].str.split()
```

I'm not sure how to join the phrases. I've tried:

```
for i in  copy.loc[nomore]:
    for x in i: 
        if x == 'no':
            print(x,x+1)
```

But this does not work. It does not recognize if `x == 'no'` and it gives and error with `x+1`.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for taking the time to read my post and assist in any way that you can. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all the "no" phrases using [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), matching `no` followed by an optional "more" and a word, and then converting that result to a list:

```py
df['phrases'].str.extractall(r'\b(no(?:\s+more)?\s+[a-zA-Z]+)')[0].to_list()
```

Output:

```
[
 'no school',
 'no homework',
 'no classes',
 'no more worries',
 'no stress',
 'no more anxiety',
 'no teachers'
]
```

You can then process the list (e.g. `print`) as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `str.findall()` and `explode()`

```
df['col'].str.findall(r'no (?:more )?\w+').explode().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['no school',
 'no homework',
 'no classes',
 'no more worries',
 'no stress',
 'no more anxiety',
 'no teachers']
```